# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, properties

I am following Laracasts' videos: [Basic Model/Controller/View Workflow](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/9).

I have a table holds contact information.

```
CREATE TABLE `about` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I am trying to pass data to view using the following code in the controller file:

```
public function index()
{
    $about = Page::where('page', 'about-me')->get(); //id = 3

    return view('about', compact('about'));
}
```

When I try to show the code as shown below,

```
@section('title')
    {{$about->title}}
@stop

@section('content')
    {!! $about->content !!}
@stop
```

I get error that says:

> Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\laragon\www\newsite\resources\views\about.blade.php)

But if I change the retrieving method in the controller file, it works.

```
public function index()
{
    $about = Page::find(3);

    return view('about', compact('about'));
}
```

When I use `dd($about)` in the first case (`where()->get()`) the data is encapsulated by an array. In the second case (`find(3)`) it displays data as expected.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 377, accepted):

When you're using `get()` you get a **collection**. In this case, you need to iterate over it to get the properties:

```
@foreach ($collection as $object)
    {{ $object->title }}
@endforeach
```

Or you could just get one of the objects by its index:

```
{{ $collection[0]->title }}
```

Or get the first object from the collection:

```
{{ $collection->first() }}
```

When you're using `find()` or `first()` you get an **object**, so you can get properties with simple:

```
{{ $object->title }}
```

Comment: yes, after execute Model->get() obtain a list with one object, by that reason always show data and I can't access that. After exexute first() then get object

Comment: After 4 HOURS of searching, reading and testing Laravel Documentation and visiting a LOT of StackOverflow questions/answers, you were the only one that mentioned that get() retrieves a collection. It was you who made me jump off the chair and realize that all my queries were correct. The problem was on the "print".
From the bottom of my heart, a big thank you for this answer! I really mean it!

Answer (score 46):

With `get()` method you get a collection (all data that match the query), try to use `first()` instead, it return only one element, like this:

```
$about = Page::where('page', 'about-me')->first();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try using first() instead of method get()

```
$about = DB::where('page', 'about-me')->first();
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21951954)

Answer (score 5):

A person might get this while working with factory functions, so I can confirm this is valid syntax:

```
$user = factory(User::class, 1)->create()->first();
```

You might see the collection instance error if you do something like:

```
$user = factory(User::class, 1)->create()->id;
```

so change it to:

```
$user = factory(User::class, 1)->create()->first()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Used Collection keyword in Controller.
Like Here..

```
public function ApiView(){
    return User::collection(Profile::all());
}
```

Here, User is Resource Name and Profile is Model Name.
Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

`$about->first()->id` or
`$stm->first()->title` and your problem is sorted out.

Comment: My code suggestion works on tinker but not on the project.

Answer (score -1):

As result of `$about = Page::where('page', 'about-me')->get()` is a laravel collection, you can get a specific attribute like *title* using `pluck()` method which is described in https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck.

```
$titles = $about->pluck( 'title' )

@foreach($titles as $title)
    {{ $title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

The stored information in about valiable, is in collection format, so you just need to loop through it.

```
@if(count($about))
   @foreach($about as $page)
    {{$page->title}}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use `where()->get()`, it returns a collection of results, see [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#building-queries) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses). Collections are used for multiple results,

you can either change your query to retrieve the first item using the `first()` method or access the first item in the collection

```
public function index()
{
    $about = Page::where('page', 'about-me')->first();

    return view('about', compact('about'));
}
```

or

```
@section('title')
    {{ $about->first()->title }}
@stop

@section('content')
    {!! $about->first()->content !!}
@stop
```