# Trying to update a column before return view with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel.
I am trying to create an update before return view but i am getting `Property [Video_Views] does not exist on this collection instance.`

This is my code

`$vidurl="WZzZdBjnjBwbMJh";
 $curvid = videos::where('Video_URL', '=', $vidurl)->get();
 $viewsarray = array($curvid->Video_Views);`

but when i remove `$viewsarray = array($curvid->Video_Views);` and let my return view work, i can get every information from $curvid into the page. Meaning my code works fine for selecting and display into the return view page. But i want to perform an update before the returnview page but for some reason the Video_Views in `$viewsarray = array($curvid->Video_Views);` doesnt exist

These are the columns in mysql table called videos [image] 
I can select all these in the return view page but i can't retrieve any info before the returnview page

Any help would be nice!

Comment: that would give me the same error because, well in "Video_Views" of my database i somewhat store the array in there. For example in my database you  will see "hi","lol","you" and using array($curvid->Video_Views) should fill the array with the amount of strings in it

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance

Comment: did you try dumping $curvid before returning the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`$curvid = videos::where('Video_URL', '=', $vidurl)->first();`

instead of `$curvid = videos::where('Video_URL', '=', $vidurl)->get();`

Or use **foreach** operator.

**Example:**

```
$vidurl="WZzZdBjnjBwbMJh";
$curvid = videos::where('Video_URL', '=', $vidurl)->get();
foreach($curvid as $vid){
    $viewsarray = array($vid->Video_Views);
}
```