# Error : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table `Authors` and table `Uploads` and I am simply trying to get all uploads for a certain author by `author_id` in the `Uploads` table.

For that purpose I have a method in my controller looking like this :

```
public function author_works()
    {

        $uploads= Upload::where('author_id', 3)->first();

        return view('author-works')->with('uploads',$uploads);
    }
```

My view is :

```
  @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Uploads</h1>
    @if(count($uploads)>0)
        @foreach($uploads as $upload)
            <div class="well">
                <h3><a href="/uploads/{{$upload->id}}">{{$upload->name}}</a> </h3>
                <small>Written on {{$upload->created_at}}</small>

            </div>
        @endforeach
      {{--  {{$uploads->links()}}--}}
    @else
        <p>No uploads found</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

When I debug with `dd($uploads);` in the controller I am seeing the following, which is actually the right record :

```
 #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "name" => "Fsdf"
    "description" => "fsdfsdffds"
    "created_at" => "2017-12-07 21:29:53"
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-07 21:29:53"
    "user_id" => 1
    "avtor_id" => 3
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "name" => "Fsdf"
    "description" => "fsdfsdffds"
    "created_at" => "2017-12-07 21:29:53"
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-07 21:29:53"
    "user_id" => 1
    "avtor_id" => 3
  ]
```

Can someone explain why am I getting the error?

Comment: `first` will give you only one record, so you can't use loop in one record, instead use `get()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `first()` method, [you're getting an object instead of collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance/41366122#41366122). Use `get()`:

```
$uploads = Upload::where('author_id', 3)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to your other one. It helped :)