# Combine multiple column for to do a foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 5 columns in my database. Here are the names of the columns:

- promo1
- promo2
- promo3
- promo4
- promo5

I would like to combine these columns to be able to make a foreach in my view.

I tried this:

```
$promos = Building::select('promo1', 'promo2', 'promo3', 'promo4', 'promo5')->where('id', $card->id)->get()->toArray();
```

and in my view :

```
@foreach($promos as $promo)
    <span>{{ $promo['promo1'] }}</span>
@endforeach
```

But I have only one result for my foreach. Instead of 5. And I can only select one by one ($ promo ['promo1'], $ promo ['promo2']) so doing a foreach would not help

Is there a way to do that? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `get()` method, [you're getting a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance/41366122#41366122). Use the `find()` method to get an object instead of collection:

```
$promos = Building::select('promo1', 'promo2', 'promo3', 'promo4', 'promo5')->find($card->id)->toArray();
```

Then you'll be able to iterate over promos:

```
@foreach ($promos as $promo)
    <span>{{ $promo }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the building object

```
$building = Building::select('promo1', 'promo2', 'promo3', 'promo4', 'promo5')->findOrFail($card->id);
```

then loop through the promos

```
@foreach ($building->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
    <span>{{ $key }} : {{ $value }}</span>
@endforeach
```

note: using the `$key` here is optional