# Error with DB query laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
$results = \DB::table('listings')
            ->select(['listings.id','listings.marina_id',\DB::raw(['min(special_offers.price) as sp_min_price','max(special_offers.price) as sp_max_price'])])
            ->join('special_offers','listings.id','=','special_offers.listing_id')
            ->where('special_offers.status',1)
            ->where("listings.status", \App\Listing::PUBLISHED)
            ->where('listings.type', \App\Listing::CHARTER)
            ->orderBy('special_offers.price','asc');
        $res = $results->get();
        \Log::info($res->sp_min_price." ".$res->sp_max_price);
```

ERROR: Array to string conversion

```
* Convert an array of column names into a delimited string.
 *
 * @param  array   $columns
 * @return string
 */
public function columnize(array $columns)
{
    return implode(', ', array_map(array($this, 'wrap'), $columns));
}
```

Why I get this error message?
How can I solve it?

Thank you!

UPDATE:
I changed the code like this:

```
$min = \DB::table('listings')
            ->selectRaw(['min(special_offers.price) as sp_min_price','max(special_offers.price) as sp_max_price'])
            ->join('special_offers','listings.id','=','special_offers.listing_id')
            ->where('special_offers.status',1)
            ->where('listings.status',\App\Listing::PUBLISHED)
            ->where('listings-type',\App\Listing::CHARTER)
            ->get();
        foreach ( $min as $sp_min ) {
            \Log::info ( $sp_min->sp_min_price." ".$sp_min->sp_max_price);
        }
```

but still the same error..

Comment: `$res` this would give you array of object so `$res->sp_min_price` will produce error instead you can iterate over result or try like `$res[0]->sp_min_price` same goes for `sp_max_price`

Comment: both `selectRaw` and `\DB:raw` expect a **string** as their first parameter, not an array. I suspect that is the problem. If not, can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

[`get()` will return a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance/41366122#41366122) but you're trying to use it as string. So, change this:

```
\Log::info($res->sp_min_price." ".$res->sp_max_price);
```

To:

```
\Log::info($res);
```

To log results.

Or you can log only `sp_min_price` and `sp_max_price` for all fetched rows:

```
\Log::info($res->pluck('sp_min_price')->toArray());
\Log::info($res->pluck('sp_max_price')->toArray());
```

Comment: I just need to get the min and the max of a column after a join and few where.

How can I do that?

Comment: @FranCode you could get results first and then use `max('price')` and `min('price')` collection methods.