# query builder get modal instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

I'm trying to get an object instance with the Query Builder of Laravel.

```
public function functionName(Request $request) {
    $seance = Seance::where('id_seance', '=', $request->idSeance)->get();

    return $seance->type_seance;
}
```

My model : `Seance(id_seance, type_seance, capacite_seance, niveau_seance, avec_coach, date_seance, heure_seance)`.

However I get this error :

> Exception: Property [type_seance] does not exist on this collection
>   instance

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get()` method return a collection object it's like an array, you need to use `first` method to get the first object:

```
public function functionName(Request $request) {
    $seance = Seance::where('id_seance', '=', $request->idSeance)->first();

    return $seance->type_seance;
}
```

You can use find() method too but `id_seance` should be the primary key of your table:

```
$seance = Seance::find($request->idSeance);
return $seance->type_seance;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `first()` instead of `get()` to get an object instead of collection of objects:

```
$seance = Seance::where('id_seance', $request->idSeance)->first();
```

The difference between these methods is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance/41366122#41366122).

Comment: If he has set up the primary key correctly he could use `Seance::find($request->idSeance)`

Comment: @Phiter with find, that's works! But with `where` it is the wrong way ?

Comment: `find()` is a shortcut for `where()->first()` and it searches by primary key only. Both ways are ok, but I'd use `find()` if you setup custom PK correctly.

Comment: Find tries to find a unique row from your table based on the table primary key (usually, we call it id). You can use where too, it's basically the same result, but find is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `get()` method, it will return a `collection` rather than an instance of the model. I suggest using the`first()` method instead.

Better yet, use`Seance::find($request->idSeance)` or `Seance::findOrFail($request->idSeance)`. This assumes that you've defined your primary key on your model correctly.