# Why looping to get data after using WHERE in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, here is my controller:

```
$topics = Topic::where('board_id', $id)->with('user')->get();
$topic = Topic::find($id);
$board = Boards::where('id', $id)->get();
return view('boards.show')->with('topics', $topics)->with('topic', $topic)->with('board', $board);
```

And here is the code for generating URL's:

```
@foreach($board as $boards)
<a href="/topics/create/{{$boards->id}}">Create New Post</a>
<p>No Posts Found</p>
@endforeach
```

But if i'm removing foreach loop, it is giving error:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

But why do, i have to loop, if it is only getting one row from the boards table?? Any solution of doing it without running for each loop???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to get just one object, you do not need [to use `get()` to get a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/laravel-property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance/41366122#41366122). Use `find()` to get an object by it's primary key:

```
$board = Boards::find($id);
```

In the view you don't need to use `@foreach` loop:

```
<a href="/topics/create/{{ $board->id }}">Create New Post</a>
```

Comment: alternative you could use first() or take(1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `Boards::find($id);` or  `Boards::findOrFail($id);` insted of `Boards::where('id', $id)->get();` for getting a single row.Also use

```
return view('boards.show')->with('topics', $topics)->with('topic', $topic)->with('board', $board);
```

to

```
return view('boards.show',[
   'topics'=> $topics,
   'topic'=> $topic,
   'board'=> $board
 ]);
```

becouse passing normal values to view using session is not a good practice

Comment: and also change href="{{ route('routeName',['id' => $user->id]))}}" , which is the best practice in laravel