# How to get id user optimaly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I now get data from html form with POST request. My app for inboxing. My code working but code of not optimaly. I can't get id user using email without loop foreach. How I can get id user without loop?

#### Code

```
public function send_message(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $to      = $request->to;
            $from    = Auth::user()->id;
            $subject = $request->subject;
            $message = $request->message;
            $to      = User::where('email', $to)->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($to as $value) {
            $to = $value['id'];
        }

        echo $to."<br>";
        echo $from."<br>";
        echo $subject."<br>";
        echo $message."<br>";

        Message::create(
            [
                'subject'=>$subject, 
                'message'=>$message, 
                'from'=>$from, 
                'to'=>$to
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method to get unique object

```
$to = User::where('email', $to)->first()->id;
```

With `get()` you have to select the first object in the collection:

```
$to = User::where('email', $to)->get()[0]->id;
```

[get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results) return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) while [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) return one User object

Answer (score 3):

Use the `first()` method:

```
User::where('email', $to)->first()->id;
```

Or `value()` if you just need ID:

```
User::where('email', $to)->value('id');
```

The difference between `first()` and `get()` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923).

Answer (score 2):

a lot of ways

```
User::where('email',$email)->first()->id;
```

OR

```
User::whereEmail('email')->first()->id;
```

you can get the id of current authenticated user via

```
Auth::id();
```