# PHP Traits "Method does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I am using [laravel-comment](https://github.com/actuallymab/laravel-comment) to enable Users to comment on each other. Therefor, I need to use both the *Commentable* and the *CanComment* trait. But when I use them together, I get an error.

User uses it like this:

```
use Commentable, CanComment {
    Commentable::comments insteadof CanComment;
}
```

And I am trying to seed the comments like this:

```
foreach (User::all() as $user) {
    $receiver = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id)->inRandomOrder()->get();
    $user->comment($receiver, $faker->text(100), 3);
}
```

Even though the *CanComment* trait has a method called `getCanBeRated`, I get an error saying that it doesn't. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to use this method on collection and not on `User` object. Use `first()` instead of `get()` to [get an object instead of collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923):

```
$receiver = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```