# laravel collection/format printing |Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

```
  $Report = Db::table('Attendance_Processed as procc')                            
                      ->leftjoin('Emp_Details', 'Emp_Details.HRApp_Emp_Id', '=', 'procc.HRApp_Emp_Id')
                            ->where('procc.Org_ID',$orgid)
                            ->where('Emp_Details.Supervisor_Emp_ID',$hrid)
                            ->whereYear('Clock_Day',$yearofdata)
                            ->whereMonth('Clock_Day',$monthofdata)   
                            ->select('Emp_Details.Emp_First_Name as name','procc.HRApp_Emp_Id as hrid',
                              'procc.Clock_Day as clockedday',
                              'procc.Time_in as timein',
                              'procc.Time_out as Timeout',
                              'procc.Total_Work_Hrs as totalworkedhours')


                           ->get()->groupBy('hrid','clockedday');
                           dd($Report);
                             return $Report;
```

the following code produce the this format

```
> Collection {#1168 ▼   #items: array:13 [▼
>     8 => Collection {#1155 ▼
>       #items: array:6 [▼
>         0 => {#934 ▼
>           +"name": "Aditi"
>           +"hrid": "8"
>           +"clockedday": "2017-10-03"
>           +"timein": "07:59:37"
>           +"Timeout": "16:52:30"
>           +"totalworkedhours": "08:52:53"
>         }
>         1 => {#935 ▼
>           +"name": "Aditi"
>           +"hrid": "8"
>           +"clockedday": "2017-10-04"
>           +"timein": "07:33:59"
>           +"Timeout": "16:31:48"
>           +"totalworkedhours": "08:57:49"
>         }
>         2 => {#936 ▶}
>         3 => {#937 ▶}
>         4 => {#938 ▶}
>         5 => {#939 ▶}
>       ]
>     }
>     20 => Collection {#1156 ▶}
>     213 => Collection {#1157 ▶}
>     11 => Collection {#1158 ▶}
>     22 => Collection {#1159 ▶}
>     10 => Collection {#1160 ▶}
>     9 => Collection {#1161 ▶}
>     28 => Collection {#1162 ▶}
>     29 => Collection {#1163 ▶}
>     16 => Collection {#1164 ▶}
>     17 => Collection {#1165 ▶}
>     25 => Collection {#1166 ▶}
>     31 => Collection {#1167 ▶}   ]
```

I am not able to print it properly on blade with foreachloop.

when i am trying to print it in blade file its showing the following error

---

"Property [hrid] does not exist on this collection instance".

---

please help me in this ..

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have a collection of collection. I guess you miss used the `groupBy`

Comment: so how to do it. it is a combined groupy

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Removing the `groupBy` will give you a Collection of objects, which will have the prop you are trying to get....

Comment: it should be  `->groupBy('hrid','clockedday')->get();` , try this and if still error remains post the view code

Comment: an(8) employee unique id(hrid)  has(6)  records but there .iam grouping unique id with respect to day to iterate in different tables

Comment: not sure what do you mean by that, are you still getting the same error? If yes then post (add it to your question) your blade file's content of using this data

Comment: letme try your way and post the comment

Comment: What are you trying to do @MadhuNair? Are you looking to look through each grouped collection? If so, why do you have it grouped in the first place ? Is this so that you can have it under titles. Please edit your question appropriately so that everyone knows what you want to do here.

Comment: is giving plain array of all elements .. with id

Comment: here iam trying to print a single employee data in one table .. i.e - (8) then 20-.....

Comment: @JigarShah i need to  print it in foreachloop in different  table  for each employee as above array ..first one is 8 -20-213 .. all in different table with respective of their inner array

Comment: got that, but you need to show the code which is throwing this error, then we would be able help :)

Comment: @JigarShah        {{dd($reportresult)}}

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Comment: @JigarShah not able to dump in blade file

Comment: just add the content where you are using foreach to print id

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i am not able to print the collection in blade for each value . i.e 8-20 in different  table with foreach

Comment: @JigarShah simple dump is not also working

Comment: @jigarShah same error fo--"{{$reportresult->first()}}" Property [hrid] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo  i am not able to iterate in laravel blade file in different table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing is that you have misplaced `groupBy`, it should be:

```
->groupBy('hrid','clockedday')->get();
```

check you have the correct data or not, then once you have the collection loop through it to print data within it.

in blade your file

```
@foreach ($result as $data)// loop through single object of collection
    {{ $data->hrid }} // or any other field
@endforeach
```

For collection within collection try like below

```
@foreach ($mainData as $result) // main collection
    @foreach ($result->secondCollection as $data)// variable containing second collection
        {{ $data->hrid }} // or any other field
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Also have a look on the [reference link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-loop-through-collection) for looping through collection

Comment: this gives a single collection array .. which i will be only able to print in a single table how can i separate employee details in different table

Comment: so keeping the `->get()->groupBy('hrid','clockedday');` gives you proper data? if so then you need to use two different `foreach`

Comment: yes but can you help me do the foeach loop .i am always getting above error for this

Comment: please post that code you have used.. if there are more lines just add lines of both  foreach you have used

Comment: <code>    i had to remove some inner part <thead>

                        <th>Date</th>
            
                    </thead>
                   foreach($reportresult as $result)
                       foreach($reportresult as $result)
                          <tr>
                          <td>{{$result->clockedday}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            endforeach
                           endforeach </code>

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: just for your information as you are new to SO: always give up vote to good question / answer to inspire users.