# Laravel 5 - Extract ID from Object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an object in laravel 5.5 **$categories** that looks like this...

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Category Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => categories
                    [primaryKey] => id
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [title] => Fruit
                            [slug] => fruit
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [title] => Fruit
                            [slug] => fruit
                        )
                )
         )
```

)

How can I get the id from this object?  I have tried both of these...

```
{{$categories->id}}
{{$categories->category->id}}
```

But they are not working, how should I be extracting this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [it's a collection and one model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923), you should use `pluck()` to get all IDs:

```
$ids = $categories->pluck('id');

@foreach ($ids as $id)
    {{ $id }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can get them one by one:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, your example makes perfect sense. Thanks for the link, will read through it