# Laravel: Eloquent relationships with *where* on parent table instead of *find*

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `posts` and `posts_contents`.
And I want to get a content from one post only if that post has `display = 1`.

*(I need two separate tables because of language support)*

**posts:**

```
id  user_id  display

1   2        0
2   2        1
3   2        0
4   2        1
```

**posts_contents**

```
id  post_id  lang_id  name    description

1   1        1        Hello   World
2   2        1        Here    Is What I wanna show!
3   3        1        Don't   Show the others
4   4        1        Hey     Display that one too
```

So in laravel I use eloquent relationships, but I just don't understand how to use it in that particular case. In the documentation I found only cases such as:

```
$p = App\Posts::find(1)->contents;
```

Which works great, however what I want is something like this:

```
$p = App\Posts::where('display',1)->contents;
```

But it doesn't work... So question is: what is the right way to do so?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

**Update**

**I need to get multiple posts at once, not just one.**

Comment: @ka_lin it's optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `find()` method like this:

```
$post = App\Posts::where('display', 1)->find($postId)->contents;
```

Then in a view for one-to-one relationship:

```
{{ $post->description }}
```

For one-to-many:

```
@foreach ($post->contents as $content)
    {{ $content->description }}
@endforeach
```

If you want to load multiple posts with contents only for one language, use filtering by a language. Use `with()` to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) contents:

```
$posts = App\Posts::where('display', 1)
    ->with(['contents' => function($q) use($langId) {
        $q->where('lang_id', $langId);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Then in a view for one-to-one:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->contents->description }}
@endforeach
```

For one-to-many:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @foreach ($post->contents as $content)
        {{ $content->description }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You can read about the difference between `find()` and `get()` methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923).

Comment: Awesome! How can I use `app('locale')` instead of `$langId`?

Comment: @MaxMaximilian it's just an example, so you should use a real ID. If `app('locale')` returns ID like `2`, you can use it. If it returns something like `en`, you'll need to do something a bit differently.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it now and you're right. Awesome! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

`App\Posts::where` will return a collection. So if you only want 1 result you should use `App\Posts::where('display',1)->first()->contents`

Comment: Good! What will `first` return?

Comment: It changes the query to use a limit of 1 result. Because of this Eloquent will return just the object (from class Posts) instead of a collection of objects. (sort of like an array from laravel)

Comment: Hmm how can I get multiple rows with content then? Using `joins` instead seems to be a little bit more tricky...

Comment: A collection as I said is "multiple rows" you just have to loop them to get their contents 1 by 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `first` method before you call any relationship:

`$p = App\Posts::where('display', 1)->first()->contents;`

Or, if you want to fetch a collection of posts, you can:

```
$posts = App\Posts::where('display', 1)->get();

$posts->each(function ($post) {
    $post->contents;
});
```

Otherwise, you will just have a Query Builder object, without the actual results you want.