# Undefined offset: 3 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a variable that contains database data to all the views with viewcomposer. But when I pass the variable to the view it says undefined index. 
Since I'm new to laravel I don't know that whether I'm doing it right in the Model please guide me if I'm wrong.

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Advertisement extends Model
{
    public static function retreive_adds()
    {
      return static::all()
      ->toArray();
    }
}
```

Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Advertisement;
class AddServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer("*", function ($view){
            $view->with('advertisement', \App\Advertisement::retreive_adds());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

view

```
<div class="sidebar-widget sidebar-adds-widget">
                  @if(($advertisement[3]->is_visible == 1) && ($advertisement[6]->position == 'homepage-left-bottom'))
                    <div class="adds-block" style="background-image:url({{ asset('uploads/advertisement_uploads') }}/{{$advertisement[1]->img_url}});">
                         <div class="inner-box">
                            <!-- <div class="text"></span></div>
                              <a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-two"></a> -->
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    @elseif(($advertisement[3]->is_visible == 0) && ($advertisement[6]->position != 'homepage-left-bottom'))
                    <div class="adds-block" style="background-image:url(images/resource/add-image-3.jpg);">
                        <div class="inner-box">
                            <div class="text">Advertisement <span> 340 x 283</span></div>
                              <a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-two">Purchase Now</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    @endif
              </div>
```

And when I var_dump the $advertisement variable I get the array containing the values from the database also

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["img_url"]=> string(34) "advertisement-image-1518768862.gif" ["link"]=> string(36) "https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries" ["is_visible"]=> int(1) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-16 08:14:22" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-02-16 08:14:22" ["position"]=> string(18) "homepage-right-top" } }
```

And if this is not the best approach, what is the best way to display a data from the db to all views ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
$advertisement[3]
```

Because `$advertisement` is an [array and not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923). You need to iterate over the collection to be able to get data from an object:

```
@foreach ($advertisement as $object)
    {{ $object->is_visible }}
@endforeach
```