# Why I can't retrieve data using a one-to-many relationship in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am trying to return data from my database and I want it to include data from the related table. It is a one-to-many relationship. However I all I get is an error

> Property [User] does not exist on this collection instance.

In my User model I have

```
//App\User.php
class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    public function systems(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\General\systems::class,'added_by','id');
   }
```

The other model, called systems I have

```
//App\Models\General\systems.php
class systems extends Model
{
    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class,'added_by','id');
}
```

In my controller I have

```
$this->systemsObject = new \App\Model\General\systems();

$systems = $this->systemsObject->get()->User;
```

according to the Laravel Documentation this should work but it isn't. I tried reversing the foreign key/local key parameters. I made the ->User uppercase, lowercase.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the [collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923), for example:

```
$systems = $this->systemsObject->get();
foreach ($systems as $system) {
    echo $system->User->name;
}
```