# Laravel models acts like array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I know about PHP Array Objects but I have never seen laravel models working like this...Its kinda strange. Heres the actual code..

```
 public function getUserChats()
{
    $users = [];
    $chats1 = Chat::where('sender_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    $chats2 = Chat::where('reciever_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    foreach ($chats2->toArray() as $chat2) {
        $user = new UserResource(User::where('id','=',$chat2['sender_id'])->first());
        array_push($users, $user);
    }
    foreach ($chats1->toArray() as $chat1) {
        $user = new UserResource(User::where('id','=',$chat1['reciever_id'])->first());
        array_push($users, $user);
    }
    return $users;
}


//The above method works but this one doesn't works
 public function getUserChats()
{
    $users = [];
    $chats1 = Chat::where('sender_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    $chats2 = Chat::where('reciever_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    foreach ($chats2->toArray() as $chat2) {
        $user = new UserResource(User::where('id','=',$chat2->sender_id)->first());
        array_push($users, $user);
    }
    foreach ($chats1->toArray() as $chat1) {
        $user = new UserResource(User::where('id','=',$chat1->reciever_id)->first());
        array_push($users, $user);
    }
    return $users;
}
```

Notice inside the for each loop how I have to access the sender_id from $chat1 and $chat2 . I want to know whats actually going on .. Its more of a theoretical 
question...Thanks for the response

Comment: You're using `$chats2->toArray()`, so you get an array as result. In your second example, leave out `->toArray()` and it should work.

Answer (score 7):

When you're using `get()` method, [you're getting a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/1227923) and not just one object, so you can iterate over the collection.

When you use `$model['property']` syntax, it works because `Model` class implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. Laravel uses the `offsetGet()` method to return object property.

Also, you don't need to use `->toArray()` method. You can iterate over a collection since `Collection` class implements [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php).

Comment: Yes thats true...But You did not get my question....Notice inside the foreach loops how the $chat2 and $chat1 variables are acting as arrays not objects!

Comment: So if $chat1 is an object why it acts like an array?

Comment: @saketr64x if you're talking about the `$object['property']` syntax, please check the updated the answer.

Comment: Oh thanks....that helps so why the first example is working...its clear.....But why the second example doesn't works?....Is it because i am calling toArray()?

Comment: @saketr64x yes. You need to remove the `toArray()` method to avoid converting objects to arrays.

Comment: that will help...thnx...I really thought the toArray method converts collections to Array() ... but what it is doing is converting each item of a collection to array...

Answer (score -1):

In your first example, the interpreter recognizes ['sender_id'] as passing text. The brackets and single quote designate this.

In your second example, the interpreter is expecting sender_id to be a function of the Laravel Framework or PHP, as a result of the use of -> after the $variable.

Comment: As far as I know all the columns belonging to a table can be used as a property in the model...so in the second example it should just recognize it as a property and not as PHP or Laravel framework

Comment: Yes this is true but in your second example the interpreter does not recognize sender_id as being a reference to a table.