# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance error with eloquent relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hello guys i want to echo my product title but am getting Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance error message using

```php
{{$order->produ->title}}
```

This is what i have in my blade file

```
<div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Customer Address :<span class="required">*</span>

                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="address" value="{{$order->customer_address}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Customer City :<span class="required">*</span>

                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="city" value="{{$order->customer_city}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Payment Amount:<span class="required">*</span>

                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="total" value="{{$order->pay_amount}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Product Orderded:<span class="required">*</span>

                            </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="total" value="{{$order->produ->title}}">
                            </div>


                        </div>
```

This is my product model  https://i.postimg.cc/fT4t8xFv/products.png

```php
    namespace App;
     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class Product extends Model
     {
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'category', 'tags', 'description', 'sizes', 'price', 'previous_price', 'stock',
        'feature_image', 'policy', 'featured', 'views', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'status'
    ];

    public static $withoutAppends = false;

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendors', 'vendorid', 'id');
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'products');
    }
}
```

This is my order model  https://i.postimg.cc/yN5YkKCT/orders.png

```php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Order extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'customerid', 'products', 'quantities', 'method', 'shipping', 'pickup_location', 'pay_amount', 
    'txnid', 'charge_id', 'order_number', 'payment_status', 'customer_email', 'customer_name', 
    'customer_phone', 'customer_address', 'customer_city', 'customer_zip', 'shipping_name', 
    'shipping_email', 'shipping_phone', 'shipping_address', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_zip', 
    'order_note', 'booking_date', 'status'
];

public $timestamps = false;

public static $withoutAppends = false;

public function produ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'orderid', 'id');
}
}
```

> ERROR = Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property \[title\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. It says that you are trying to get a property from the collection instance instead of the `Product` item, which means you need to iterate over the products and print out its title. So you can use it like this:

```
@foreach($order->produ as $product)
    <li>{{ $product->title }}</li>
@endforeach
```