# Property [subcategory] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

First time working with `eloquent` relationship. I'm trying to access the `subcategory method` yet I get this error:

> Property [subcategory] does not exist on this collection instance.

New to laravel so any help would be appreciated!

**blade**

```
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Sub-category</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($categories as $cat)
                            <tr>
                                <td scope="row">{{$cat->name}}</td> 

                                 //error here
                                @foreach ($categories->subcategory as $item)
                                    <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
                                @endforeach

                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ([
    'name'
]);

public function subcategory(Type $var = null)
{
    # code...
    return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class,'category_id','id');
}
}
```

**subcategory model**

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ([
        'category_id',
        'name'
    ]);

```
public function category(Type $var = null)
{
    # code...
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
}
```

**controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    // dd($categories);
    return view('settings.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property \[title\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing wrong in foreach loop. Your second foreach loop will be like

```
@foreach ($categories as $cat)
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{$cat->name}}</td> 
        @foreach ($cat->subcategory as $item)
        <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
        @endforeach

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

your current object is `$cat` and `$categories` is a collection.

Comment: Oh thank you! I thought I would still have to work with the `$categories` thank you!

Comment: relation always belong to an object. not on collection.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `subcategory` of `$categories` collection not on one model `$cat`. So change your `@foreach` method to

```
@foreach ($cat->subcategory as $item)
   <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 @foreach ($cat->subcategory as $item)        
    <td>{{$item->name}}</td>    
 @endforeach
```