# How to get column data using eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wan't to get the `id` of `sub-category` that is under `category`. I tried passing the value of `id` in the route file using

> $categories->subcategory->id

However it gives me an error of:

> Property [subcategory] does not exist on this collection instance.

Here's my relationship:

**Category**

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ([
        'name'
    ]);

    public function subcategory(Type $var = null)
    {
        # code...
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class,'category_id','id');
    }
}
```

And here's my **blade**

```php
<form action="{{route('subcategory.update', $categories->subcategory->id)}}">
    <div class="modal-body">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```php
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    // dd($categories);
    return view('settings.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property \[title\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Comment: As @dparoli said, `subcategory` is a `hasMany` relation, so in `$category->subcategory` you have multiple in a collection, not one `subcategory`. you need to access one of them to get the ID `$category->subcategory[0]->id` if there is at least one result.

Comment: `$categories` is already a collection, and the `subcategory()` relationship is a collection too because it is a `hasMany` and should be named `subcategories()`, so now you have this error on `$categories` but you will have the same error on property `id` if you do `$categories[0]->subcategory->id`. So you have to decide if you want to retrieve multiple records or only one, but you didn't post the controller code.

Comment: I will edit post to show Controller code @dparoli

Comment: The function posted is a `create()` so you are probably trying to show the creation form for some model, it's unclear if it is a `Category` or `Subcategory` one. But the form posted has an action that point  to an update route. I cannot understand what you are trying to do but I don't want to debug all your code, this is not how SO works. The error posted has already good answers in the link provided, after you solved that error you can open a new question with other error you would have and the minimal sample code required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your `$categories` variable is a collection of `Category::class` ?

Keep in mind that the `subcategory` function will return multiple items, because of the `HasMany`

#### You could try the following:

```
$categories->first()->subcategory->first()->id
```

**OR**

```
$categories->subcategory->first()->id
```

If not, you could add the `subcategory` relationship to the `Category::class` to the `$with` array, so it's automatically loaded in. And try again.

#### To use the `$with` array:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['subcategory'];
}
```

Comment: How does that `$with` array syntax looks like? I'm sorry I'm new to Laravel

Comment: No problem! it is : `protected $with = ['subcategory'];` I will update the answer with an example

Comment: Hello, I got it working now. How does `$categories->first()->subcategory->first()->id` work?

Comment: The `$categories` variable contains an Collection of categories if you defined it in your controller with `$categories = Category::all()` or `$categories = 
 Category::get()` so calling `->first()` on it returns the first instance out of the collection. The same goes for `subcategory` because it is a `HasMany` it returns an Collection instance instead of a single Model instance. finally you want the `->id` attribute from a single subcategory. You can only get the id on a single instance, or by using `subcategory->pluck('id')` to get them all. Hope this helps!