# How to resolve delete/edit button with string primary key does'nt work in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, primary-key, delete-row

NOTE : I use the same delete/edit function for all the tables in my project.

```
function confirmDelete(link, id) {
    ...
    .then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
      window.location.href = "/del-"+link+id;
      swal("Supprimé avec succès!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
    ...
  }
```

Delete function in `PersonnelController` :

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $cin)
{
    $personnel = Personnel::findOrFail($cin);
    $personnel -> delete();
    redirect('/personnel');
}
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/del-pers/{cin}', 'PersonnelController@destroy')->name('personnel.destroy');
```

the edit button shows me this error in edit page :

```
Property [cin] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

The **`Show`** button works properly and show me the record, but the delete button does'nt work :

```
<a class="btn btn-sm bu5" href="/detail-pers/{{ $pers->cin }}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-sm bu5" href="/edit-pers/{{ $pers->cin }}"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-sm bu5" onclick="confirmDelete('pers/', {{$pers->cin}})"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

[image: Delete button problem with red vector]

The `CIN` is the primary key

*for example: **BB1194***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance the solution at this might work for.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide us with your routes, we can give you a better answer.
Anyhow, if you define your delete rout like below

```
Route::get('del-pers/{id}' , ....)
```

It should work properly.
Alternatively, you can send your request withquery parameters like 'del-pers?cid=55' and get it through

```
$request->cid
```

inside your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I can't do that, because it will be a direct delete, and my function ask the user to confirm the delete operation, then he presses on OK button. I added the route in my question !!