# Property [firstName] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

My User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstName', 'secondName', 'email', 'city', 'phoneNumber', 'password', 'profilePicture'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ratings::class, 'ratings_has_users', 'users_id', 'ratings_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

My Ratings Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ratings extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ratings_has_users', 'users_id', 'ratings_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

MIgration to create table 'ratings_has_users'

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRatingsHasUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ratings_has_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('ratings_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('ratings_has_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('users_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
        });

        Schema::table('ratings_has_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('ratings_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('ratings');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ratings_has_users');
    }
}
```

Migration to create 'users' table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstName',55);
            $table->string('secondName',55);
            $table->string('email',55)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('city',55);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('phoneNumber',11);
            $table->string('profilePicture',255)->default('profile.jpg');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Migration to create 'ratings' table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRatingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('stars');
            $table->mediumText('note');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ratings');
    }
}
```

And code in my blade:

```
@foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {{ dd($rating->user->firstName) }}
@endforeach
```

I don't know why I see this error message: **Property [firstName] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /data/www/twoj-trener/resources/views/trainer_page/reviews.blade.php)**

When I change code on this:

```
@foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {{ dd($rating->user) }}
@endforeach
```

I got this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1291 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: `Rating`'s `user` relationship method returns a `BelongsToMany` (plural), will always be a Collection

Comment: similar issue to here I would assume: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance

Answer (score 0):

**Ratings** has **user**(better name **users**, because **belongsToMany**) relation method. If **belongsToMany** relation that relation method(in this case **user**) will give the Collection (list related records).

You can do something like below

```
$rating->user->first()->firstName
```

Comment: This ```$rating->user->first()->firstName``` not working I got ```Trying to get property 'firstName' of non-object```

Comment: @Sothot are you sure rating has related user? If `$rating->user->first()` is null then getting properties will not work

Answer (score 0):

The relation between rating and user should be `users()` (with an S for plural) since it's a belongToMany one with a pivot table.

**If you want ratings to be unique per user**, consider changing your migration of ratings table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('stars');
            $table->mediumText('note');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

and change the relation to `belongsTo`

**if your structure is correct as it is**, you will need to get the user before accessing its attribute

```
@foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {{ dd($rating->users->first() ?? $rating->users->first()->firstName) }}
@endforeach
```