# Property [column] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

#### Unable to access Laravel Eloquent Relationship

---

While using `get()` method

```
        $user = User::find(1)->get(); 
        
        $foo = $user->posts->title;
```

> Property [posts] does not exist on this collection instance.

---

After using [`first()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/14138027) method

```
        $user = User::find(1)->first(); 
        
        $foo = $user->posts->title;
```

Or

```
        $user = User::with('posts')->first(); 
        
        $foo = $user->posts->title;
```

> Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.

---

#### Files & Configuration

`App\Models\User.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Post;

class User extends Model
{

    public function posts(){

        return $this->hasMany(
                                Post::class, 
                                'post_code', 
                                'code'
                            );
    }

}
```

`App\Models\Post.php`

```
namespace App\Models;


class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'code', 'tags'];
    
}
```

---

`Post` table where `id` field is PK. But I want to make relation with `code` field.

| id | title | code | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monalisa | MH01 | arts |
| 2 | AI | MH01 | science |

`User` table in which `post_code` has many relation with `Post` table.

| id | name | post_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | MH01 |

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `User::find(1);` without anything after? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: `$user = User::findOrFail(1);` then `$user->getAddress->city;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to give credit to [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366122/14138027).

The `get()` will give collections and `first()` gives objects. Hence, I've used `first()` method with `with('relation')` method which accept `relation` name as parameter.

We can access it by using its index with `[]` operator

```
        $user = User::with('posts')->first(); 
        
        $title = $user->posts[0]->title;
        $name = $statements->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The find method looks like this

```
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    return $this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
}
```

This method returns first, so you need to do this `$user = User::find(1);` and this will return the user.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` give you a model instance, where `findOrFail()` give you a model instance + it will raise a 404 error if data is empty :

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
```

A user hasMany `posts()`,  so you need to make a loop to get the data. Before check if the relation has data, otherwise it will throw an error :

```
if($user->posts()->exists()) {
   foreach($user->posts as $key => $value){
          echo $value->title;
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not mandatory to `find()` if you can suggest some other method. That will do.