# Why show Property [banner_image] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an error called

> Why show Property (post_meta_keyword) does not exist on this collection instance.

I want to put `post_meta_keyword` property to my meta tag, but it show does not exist on this collection.

Here's my Controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $banners = Banner::all();
        
        return view('pages/home', compact('posts', 'banners'));
    }
}
```

Here's my meta tags in layouts html:

```
<title>@yield('title','A default title')</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('post_meta_keyword','some default keywords')">
<meta name="description" content="@yield('post_meta_description','default description')">
<link rel="canonical" href="{{url()->current()}}" />
```

And here's my home.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.layouts')
@section('post_meta_keyword', $posts->post_meta_keyword)
@section('post_meta_description', $posts->post_meta_description)
```

I also want to call my banner property without looping, it also show does not exist on this collection

Here's my home.blade.php for banner property:

```
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="{{ $banners->banner_image }}" alt="">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>{{ $banners->banner_title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ $banners->banner_caption }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to call property without looping?

Comment: `all()` and `get()` gives you a collection. you can't get property from a collection without looping through it. does this answer your question? [Property \[title\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Comment: So, how to get property without looping?

Comment: you have to use `first()`. but this will give you only one instance.

Comment: Okey, i got it.. Thankyou