# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance exception

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel. I want to fetch all the values in `id` column from table `skills`. It is auto incrementing and the primary key of the table.

The following shows my function to get skills:

```php
public function getSkillList(){
    $skill = Skills::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
    echo $skill->id;
```

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

I get this error. Can anyone please help to fix this?

Comment: `->get()` returns a Collection of `Skills` instances, like `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...]`, so you can't access `->id`, since it doesn't know which instance you're trying to access. You need to iterate, like `foreach($skill as $skill){ echo $skill->id; }`. Or, `echo Skills::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first()->id;`

Comment: Sidenote, this question is asked _multiple times per week on Stackoverflow_. Did you search your error at all before posting this? I'm voting to close as duplicate: [Property \[title\] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance)

Comment: If you try to dd($skill); the response will be a collection. If you try to get $skill->id that error will be thrown because you are trying to access the id but it's not accessible that way. If you try to foreach every object, then you can access each id you like.

Answer (score 2):

This question is known before, you just have to search for your error and you will find a lot of answers.

however hier is your answer:

```
$skills = Skills::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

foreach($skills as $skill) 
{
echo $skill->id;
}
```

Comment: See comment below, you don't need `::query()` at all.

Comment: @TimLewis for code styling and for indexing in the IDE is it nice to have the query(); :)

Comment: That's IDE-specific and doesn't apply to everyone though; answers here should be generic. For example, adding `query()` on my IDE does nothing except for make my code longer and more redundant...

Comment: You are right I will remove it then :) thx for the tip :D

Answer (score 1):

`get();` function returns a collection of your `Skills` entity. You have to use loop to get the `id` and other values.

```
public function getSkillList() {
    $skill = Skills::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
    if (!empty($skill)) {
     foreach ($skill as $value) {
       echo $value->id;
     }
    } else {
     return [];
    }
}
```

to get particular row data use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

```
$skills = Skills::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();
echo $skills->id;
```

Also, you can get more information from Laravel docs.

Comment: thanks, Tim. Forgot to remove `query()`. I have updated the answer.