# Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance. / Laravel - with() Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get data with relations from controller but can't use in blade

Controller..

`$employees =  Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('people')->get();`

Blade, I use in foreach like  ..

`$employee->people->image`

But it gives error

> Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance.

When I dd($employees)

[image]

Comment: Does the people model has a column image?

Comment: There might be a record on the result that doesn't have a value to the image property, what you should do is user dd($employees); to visualize the collation and see if image exist in all rows or not

Comment: what is the relation type of people method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that the variable $employee (which contains model Post btw)
has relation 1:N to People I assume

meaning you have to loop the people collection returned by the relation

e.g.

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
   @foreach($employee->people as $person)
      {{ $person->image }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

You must foreach people relationship , you are getting collection with people for that post so you must foreach it because relationship return array with all people per post.

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
   @foreach($employee->people as $user)
      {{ $user->image }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you want only one from people you could use

```
$employee->people->first()->image
```

Whin this way you should use

```
@if( $employee->people->first()->image)
    {{ $employee->people->first()->image }}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks I get that

Answer (score 0):

Please check you post model does it have relation function defined?

```
public function people() {
        return $this->hasMany(people::class); // Add localID and foreign_key ID as param if requires
 }
```

Also check image property is there

Please check
[Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance) hope this help

Answer (score 0):

In this case, each post has a lot of people. So, you need to specify from which people you want to get the information.
For example, this code can be work:

```
$employee->people->first()->image
```

Because you are getting the image from the first people. But I don't recommend this code because you are getting all people of a post and use just one of them and it's not optimized.

But if you want to show all people use this:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee) 
    @foreach($employee->people as $person)
        {{ $person->image }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```